# How can I automate my Powershell script for dailysanity check for www.vodafone.de page?

Tags: powershell

When I click on https://www.vodafone.de/shop/authentifizierung.html?btype=decide&configURL=%2Fscripts%2Fecommerce.config.auth.json&icmp=mobilfunk:vvl it asks me for my msisdn number. When I give my msisdn number it ask me to click 'request sms code'.

Now I have written my Powershell script & everything is running until I give my msisdn number through script & error occurs "The cell phone number you entered is incorrect. Did you make a typing error? Or is it not a Vodafone number? Please try again".

I have cross-checked variable datatype of "number" & the one that I am using. Everything is right. But why it's not accepting the msisdn number that I am passing. When I enter that msisdn number manually it works.

My Powershell code:

```
 $number = "0123345687"
 $number.gettype().fullname
 $ie = New-Object -Com 'internetexplorer.application' ;
 $ie.visible=$true;
 $url = "www.vodafone.de"
 write-Host "$url"
 [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 
 [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
 $href= ((Invoke-WebRequest $url).Links|Where innerText -like 
 “Mobilfunk”).href
 write-host "$href"
 $webreq = Invoke-WebRequest $url$href 
 $webreq.Content |Out-File C:\Users\Puranikn\tmp.txt
 $authentication=Select-String -Path "C:\Users\Puranikn\tmp.txt" -Pattern 
 'config.auth.json'
 $vvlurl= ("$authentication" -split '"')[1]
 write-host $vvlurl

$ie.navigate("https://www.vodafone.de/shop/authentifizierung.html? 
btype=decide&configURL=%2Fscripts%2Fecommerce.config.auth.json&
icmp=mobilfunk:vvl");
While ($ie.Busy -eq $true) {Start-Sleep -Seconds 20;}
$ie.Document.getElementById("msisdn").value=$number
#$div = $ie.Document.getElementsByClassName('ws2-btn btn-red') | where- 
object {$_.span -eq 'SMS-Code anfordern'}
$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$submitButton = $ie.Document.getElementsByClassName('ws2-btn btn-red') | 
Select-Object -First 1
$submitButton.click()
```

Comment: Without showing your PowerShell script, it is **very unlikely** anyone can help you with this..

Comment: Thankyou Theo. And there is my edited question which also contains code

Answer (score 1):

As for this...

> But I am not getting what should be the Codeline to click on
>   'request-sms code'

... it's because you never asked for it.

Example site navigation to have a click event.

```
# Set your properteis
$password = '1234'
$loginUrl = 'https://pwpush.com'

# Create your browser session
$ie = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application
$ie.visible = $true
$ie.navigate($loginUrl)

# Pause the browser to wait for load
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 1 }

# Navigate the page enter data
($ie.document.getElementById('password_payload') | 
select -first 1).value = $password

Start-Sleep -Seconds 1 

<#
Navigate to the element to take action on. 
#>
$ie.Document.getElementsByName('commit').Item().Click()
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
```

This can be the different per site or site could change it without notice. So, you have to scrape the site to find the right one.

```
$Pwpush = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://pwpush.com' -SessionVariable pw
$Pwpush.AllElements
$Pwpush.Forms
$Pwpush.Forms.Fields
$Pwpush.Forms[0] | Format-List -Force
```

Comment: Hey Hello,
Which element needs to be called in $ie.Document.getElementsByName() to take click action on "SMS-Code anfordern",inyour above script it's "commit" for "push it". Similarly I am not getting what should be the element for "Request SMS code" or if you are not using german translation it will be "SMS-Code anfordern"

Comment: The html code for the page is  as below:-
The html code for it is :-
<a class="ws2-btn btn-red" ng-show="currentStep === 1" ng-click="shopAuth.submitAuthForm(1)">
                    <span>SMS-Code anfordern</span>
                    <svg class="i-sml i-red link-arrow"><use xlink:href="/simplicity/svgdefs.svg#i-arrow-ws2-right-sml"></use></svg>
                </a>

Comment: Hey hello,
I have progressed a bit & i have edited the code with my new script where i have now submit button which is clicked. But on webpage it says :- "The cell phone number you entered is incorrect. Did you make a typing error? Or is it not a Vodafone number? Please try again"